# Localhost intermittently loads assets on WebBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I very occasionally have to refresh several times before all my assets are loaded properly when running my localhost. There's quite a few js libraries going on ( which I believe is root cause of this issue ).

1/5 refreshes will load all my assets properly. The others will either skip a .js library or a css library or both.

Why is this happening? And how can I ensure that it will load all the assets ( without precompiling ) ?